# Find angle of a right triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Ok, so this question is from a practice exam. Looks very simple and basic, but I'm not very good at math, so I'm having trouble setting up the problem.

One acute angle of a right triangle is not less than 30° more than twice the other acute angle. What are the possible measures of the larger angle?

I know that the sum of all angles equal to 180° and that one side equals 90° so there is a 90° left for the other two remaining angles but I don't know how to divide it. To be honest I don't  I understand the problem where it says "less than 30° more than twice" if someone can put it in different words or explain. I need a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're off to a good start! Some people learn better geometrically, however I'll do this algebraically. Like you said, we have two angles we're trying to find the "size" of. Let's call them $\angle a$ and $\angle b$. You've already pointed out that

$$\angle a+\angle b=90^\circ$$

Now, one of these angles must be smaller than the other (or the same size if we have an isosceles triangle), so let's assume that $\angle a$ is the smaller of the two. But notice then that $\angle a\le45^\circ$, as if $\angle a>45^\circ$ then $\angle a$ is bigger than $\angle b$ (can you see why?)

Now, we decipher the actual question. It says that *one of* the acute angles is *not less* than $30^\circ$ plus twice the other angle. To say that one angle is **not less** than another is actually the same as saying it is **greater or equal to** that other angle. But this means that the bigger angle must be greater than or equal to $30^\circ$ and twice the other, smaller angle (ask yourself, is it clear why it is the *bigger* angle that is greater than the other expression?). In our notation, this means that

$$\angle b\ge2\angle a+30^\circ$$

Remember! $\angle a+\angle b=90^\circ$, so $\angle a=90^\circ-\angle b$. Substituting this in gives

$$\angle b\ge2(90^\circ-\angle b)+30^\circ$=180^\circ-2\angle b+30^\circ$$

Moving the angle over to the other side of the equality gives:

$$3\angle b\ge180^\circ+30^\circ=210^\circ$$

so

$$3\angle b\ge 210^\circ$$

I'll leave the division to you. The only thing left to consider is just  *how big* can the larger of the two angles get? (Hint: could it be larger than $90^\circ$? Could it even be $90^\circ$?)

Answer (score 1):

$$A+B+C=180°$$
$$B=90°$$
$$A>=2C+30$$

Hence,
$$A+C=90°$$
$$A>=2C+30°$$

Let us set $A=2C+30°$, getting $2C+30°+C=90°$, so $C=20°$ and $A=70°$.
If $C$ is decreased then $A$, will still meet the equals below "Hence," so $A>=70°$.